# AWS ECS: Load Balancing multiple containers under a single service

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-ecs, aws-application-load-balancer

Suppose I have a task definition with 2 nginx containers. Now when I make a service (EC2 launch type) using this task definition and try to add an ALB to it I am able to only choose one "container to load balance". How can I set it up so I am able to load balance the other container too using the same ALB ?

What I have tried and understood is: Suppose I am running 2 tasks using above definition under a single service. So there will be 4 containers running (2 each of container_1 and container_2). When I choose the container_1 to load balance during service ALB creation, ECS will create a target group and put the instance and the dynamic ports of container_1 as targets. This target group will then be mapped to the ALB's rules. This works for me.

But now if I want to have a rule setup for my other set of containers the only way I see is to make the target group myself by hardcoding the dynamic ports of container_2's containers, which is less than ideal.

A use case that I can think of right now is suppose one container is running the frontend and another is running the backend. So I want url's like /my-app/pages/* to go to frontend containers and /my-app/apis/* to go to backend containers. I'm sure there are better examples/use cases but this is all I can think of right now.

So, how would I go about setting this up ?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's follow the documentation and recommendations from AWS on why more than 1 containers are allowed in a task. From the documentation [1]

> When the following conditions are required, we recommend that you
> deploy your containers in a single task definition:
>
> - Your containers share a common lifecycle (that is, they are launched
>   and terminated together).
> - Your containers must run on the same underlying host (that is, one
>   container references the other on a localhost port).
> - You require that your containers share resources.
> - Your containers share data volumes.
>
> Otherwise, you should define your containers in separate tasks
> definitions so that you can scale, provision, and deprovision them
> separately.

[1] https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/application_architecture.html

For your use-case of frontend and backend applications, two different services is the right way. 2 ECS Services, with 1 TaskDefinition and 1 Container each.

As to how both should integrate with each other, via URL or service names (Microservice Mesh) is another topic and discussion.

Comment: Right I understand. Frankly, I'm currently just learning and this scenario of multiple containers in 1 definition is just something I wanted to try while exploring ECS. The frontend backend usecase is just something I came up with on the spot to try and better explain what I wanted to do. Regardless, I searched a bit more and found out it is possible to do what I want by registering multiple target groups (1 for each container) with ALB(s). The problem currently is it cannot be done from the console. It can only be done via API or SDK or CF templates. Thanks!